# How do i make toggle from left whitout jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, toggle

How do i make toggle from left without using jquery-ui

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">This is a paragraph.</div>

<button>my toggle</button>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    background:khaki;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kashifkiduniya/w6xzq5n4/1/)

Comment: You could use CSS transition if you don't want to us jQuery/Javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anujbhai/95ku88hr/). I have reinserted the paragraph within '`<div id="toggle_text"></div>`' and used jQuery's '`animate()`' method to alter its `left` position so that it appears to be sliding from left direction. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.
Stay Bless