# How to make a div slide left when I click a button

Tags: jquery

How can I make a div slide left when I click a button

Can someone please correct me.

```
var y = 0;

if (y == 0) {
    $(function(){
        $("#click").click(function() {
            $("#slide").animate({ left: '+=200px' }, 'slow');
            y = 1;
        });  
    });
}
else {
    $(function(){
        $("#click").click(function(){
            $("#slide").animate({ left: '-=200px' }, 'slow');
        });            
    });
}
```

Comment: may be this would help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322098/how-can-i-make-toggle-from-left-whitout-jquery-ui/28359216#28359216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the `if` condition is executed only once at the page load, so only one click handler in the `if` block is executed.

You need to have a single click handler registered, then need to check the condition within the click handler and execute the relevant code blocks inside that handler

```
$(function () {
    var y = 0;
    $("#click").click(function () {
        if (y == 0) {
            $("#slide").animate({
                left: '+=200px'
            }, 'slow');
            y = 1;
        } else {
            $("#slide").animate({
                left: '-=200px'
            }, 'slow');
            y = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var y = 0;
  $("#click").click(function() {
    if (y == 0) {
      $("#slide").animate({
        left: '+=200px'
      }, 'slow');
      y = 1;
    } else {
      $("#slide").animate({
        left: '-=200px'
      }, 'slow');
      y = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#slide {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">click</button>
<div id="slide">slide</div>
```

---

You can shorten the code using a ternary operator like

```
$(function () {
    var y = true;
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $("#slide").animate({
            left: y ? '+=200px' : '-=200px'
        }, 'slow');
        y = !y;
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var y = true;
  $("#click").click(function() {
    $("#slide").animate({
      left: y ? '+=200px' : '-=200px'
    }, 'slow');
    y = !y;
  });
});
```

```css
#slide {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">click</button>
<div id="slide">slide</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put `if condition` in the right place , Here you are a working example

```js
var y = 0;


$(function() {
  $("#click").click(function() {
    if (y == 0) {
      $("#slide").animate({"left": '+=200px'}, 'slow');
      y = 1;
    } else {
      $("#slide").animate({"left": '-=200px'}, 'slow');
      y = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #abc;
  left: 50px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="click" value="Click Me !" />
<div id="slide" class="block"></div>
```